# How can I determine the IP address I get from torify (tor) in shell command line (linux)?

Tags: linux, tor

How can I determine the IP address I get from torify (tor) in shell command line (linux) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to query an outside service, something like `whatismyipaddress.com` or so. I use, for instance,

```
wget 216.146.38.70:80 -O - -o /dev/null | cut -d" " -f6 | sed 's/<\/body><\/html>//'
```

for use outside of tor. With torify, you can just use:

```
torify 2> /dev/null wget 216.146.38.70:80 -O - -o /dev/null | cut -d" " -f6 | sed 's/<\/body><\/html>//'
```

Error redirection is added to take care of `torify`'s (many) error messages.

Comment: BRILLIANT solution !